# How to display image as watermark using django-easy-pdf

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.8, xhtml2pdf

Let's say i have a table in my pdf template as below and i just want the image appear as watermark behind my table, can anyone help me?

```
{% block content %}
<img style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 50px; z-index:100" src="{{LOGO_URL | get64 }}">

<fieldset style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <table width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border: solid 1px #000000; background-color:#CCCCCC; padding:5px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>{% trans "CLAIMANT DETAILS" %}</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</fieldset>
{% endblock content %}
```

I've able to load the image on the generated PDF, however i cant use it as watermark where it should overlay it behind my table for example.

I've tried using CSS to make it overlay but also failed.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind position the watermark by hand and display it on all pages you can do as follow:

add this in your css:

```
@page {
    @frame body {
        -pdf-frame-content: waterMarkContent;
        top:0.5cm;
        margin-left: 19cm;
    }
}
```

and add this html anywhere in your template

```
<div id="waterMarkContent">
    {%block page_body%}
    <img src="{{image_url}}" width="2cm">
    {%endblock%}
</div>
```